# SQL Syntax error first time

Tags: mysql

This is my first venture into the world of MySQL. However, i'm getting this error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '9/30/2012 12:00:00 AM', '10/1/2012 12:00:00 AM', '9/30/2012 12:00:00 AM', '', ' at line 1
```

The commandtext is quite long, so I am sorry. Also, YES I KNOW ABOUT SQL INJECTION and how to prevent it; however, this program will be internal use only and does not run the risk of this.

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `" + TableName + "`";
                cmd.CommandText += "(ControlNumber, Jur_ID, Jur_Status, Jur_Collected, 1Jur_Yr, 1Jur_Install, 1Jur_Amt, 1Jur_Paid, 1Jur_Due, 1Jur_DtDue, 1Jur_FinalDue, 1Jur_DtPaid, 1Jur_Thru, ";
                cmd.CommandText += "2Jur_Yr, 2Jur_Install, 2Jur_Amt, 2Jur_Paid, 2Jur_Due, 2Jur_DtDue, 2Jur_FinalDue, 2Jur_DtPaid, 2Jur_Thru, 3Jur_Yr, 3Jur_Install, 3Jur_Amt, 3Jur_Paid, 3Jur_Due, 3Jur_DtDue, 3Jur_FinalDue, 3Jur_DtPaid, 3Jur_Thru, ";
                cmd.CommandText += "4Jur_Yr, 4Jur_Install, 4Jur_Amt, 4Jur_Paid, 4Jur_Due, 4Jur_DtDue, 4Jur_FinalDue, 4Jur_DtPaid, 4Jur_Thru, Jur_PayNotes, Jur_OtherNotes, MillageRate, AssessedValue, LandValue, ImprovedValue, TotalValue, ";
                cmd.CommandText += "1Jur_DelAmount, 2Jur_DelAmount, 3Jur_DelAmount, 4Jur_DelAmount, Unincorporated, Ex_Homestead, Ex_Disabled, Ex_Veteran, Ex_Mortgage, Ex_Star, Ex_Elderly, Ex_Other, 1Jur_Del, 2Jur_Del, 3Jur_Del, 4Jur_Del, ";
                cmd.CommandText += "DelVerifiedBy, MilNextDue, DelOverideNotes, SpokeTo, LumpSum, SchoolTax, PriorYearDel, 1Jur_Partial, 2Jur_Partial, 3Jur_Partial, 4Jur_Partial, 1Jur_Timely, 2Jur_Timely, 3Jur_Timely, 4Jur_Timely, ";
                cmd.CommandText += "1Jur_FrDue, 2Jur_FrDue, 3Jur_FrDue, 4Jur_FrDue, LowestDiscount, PaidDiscount, NoDiscount, PrimaryAuth, OtherAuth, MultiParcel, LandImprov, PriorYearDelq, AnyRedeemed, SpecialAssess, AnyExemptions, ";
                cmd.CommandText += "NextYearAssessment, LastYearPaid, TaxSale, TaxRateArea, Ex_OwnerOccupied) ";
                cmd.CommandText += "VALUES ";
                cmd.CommandText += "("+ r["ControlNumber"] +", "+ r["Jur_ID"] +", '"+ r["Jur_Status"] +"', '"+ r["Jur_Collected"] +"', '"+ r["1Jur_Yr"] +"', '"+ r["1Jur_Install"] +"', "+ r["1Jur_Amt"] +", "+ r["1Jur_Paid"] +", "+ r["1Jur_Due"] +", '"+ r["1Jur_DtDue"] +"', '"+ r["1Jur_FinalDue"] +"', '"+ r["1Jur_DtPaid"] +"', '"+ r["1Jur_Thru"] +"', ";
                cmd.CommandText += "'"+ r["2Jur_Yr"] +"', '"+ r["2Jur_Install"] +"', "+ r["2Jur_Amt"] +", "+ r["2Jur_Paid"] +", "+ r["2Jur_Due"] +", '"+ r["2Jur_DtDue"] +"', '"+ r["2Jur_FinalDue"] +"', '"+ r["2Jur_DtPaid"] +"', '"+ r["2Jur_Thru"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_Yr"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_Install"] +"', "+ r["3Jur_Amt"] +", "+ r["3Jur_Paid"] +", "+ r["3Jur_Due"] +", '"+ r["3Jur_DtDue"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_FinalDue"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_DtPaid"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_Thru"] +"', ";
                cmd.CommandText += "'"+ r["4Jur_Yr"] +"', '"+ r["4Jur_Install"] +"', "+ r["4Jur_Amt"] +", "+ r["4Jur_Paid"] +", "+ r["4Jur_Due"] +", '"+ r["4Jur_DtDue"] +"', '"+ r["4Jur_FinalDue"] +"', '"+ r["4Jur_DtPaid"] +"', '"+ r["4Jur_Thru"] +"', '"+ r["Jur_PayNotes"] +"', '"+ r["Jur_OtherNotes"] +"', "+ r["MillageRate"] +", "+ r["AssessedValue"] +", "+ r["LandValue"] +", "+ r["ImprovedValue"] +", "+ r["TotalValue"] +", ";
                cmd.CommandText += ""+ r["1Jur_DelAmount"] +", "+ r["2Jur_DelAmount"] +", "+ r["3Jur_DelAmount"] +", "+ r["4Jur_DelAmount"] +", '"+ r["Unincorporated"] +"', '"+ r["Ex_Homestead"] +"', '"+ r["Ex_Disabled"] +"', '"+ r["Ex_Veteran"] +"', '"+ r["Ex_Mortgage"] +"', '"+ r["Ex_Star"] +"', '"+ r["Ex_Elderly"] +"', '"+ r["Ex_Other"] +"', '"+ r["1Jur_Del"] +"', '"+ r["2Jur_Del"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_Del"] +"', '"+ r["4Jur_Del"] +"', ";
                cmd.CommandText += "'"+ r["DelVerifiedBy"] +"', "+ r["MilNextDue"] +", '"+ r["DelOverideNotes"] +"', '"+ r["SpokeTo"] +"', '"+ r["LumpSum"] +"', '"+ r["SchoolTax"] +"', '"+ r["PriorYearDel"] +"', '"+ r["1Jur_Partial"] +"', '"+ r["2Jur_Partial"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_Partial"] +"', '"+ r["4Jur_Partial"] +"', '"+ r["1Jur_Timely"] +"', '"+ r["2Jur_Timely"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_Timely"] +"', '"+ r["4Jur_Timely"] +"', ";
                cmd.CommandText += "'"+ r["1Jur_FrDue"] +"', '"+ r["2Jur_FrDue"] +"', '"+ r["3Jur_FrDue"] +"', '"+ r["4Jur_FrDue"] +"', "+ r["LowestDiscount"] +", '"+ r["PaidDiscount"] +"', '"+ r["NoDiscount"] +"', '"+ r["PrimaryAuth"] +"', '"+ r["OtherAuth"] +"', '"+ r["MultiParcel"] +"', '"+ r["LandImprov"] +"', '"+ r["PriorYearDelq"] +"', '"+ r["AnyRedeemed"] +"', '"+ r["SpecialAssess"] +"', '"+ r["AnyExemptions"] +"', ";
                cmd.CommandText += ""+ r["NextYearAssessment"] +", '"+ r["LastYearPaid"] +"', '"+ r["TaxSale"] +"', '"+ r["TaxRateArea"] +"', '"+ r["Ex_OwnerOccupied"]+ "'); ";

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


cmd.CommandText = INSERT INTO `FNF Taxes`(ControlNumber, Jur_ID, Jur_Status, Jur_Collected, 1Jur_Yr, 1Jur_Install, 1Jur_Amt, 1Jur_Paid, 1Jur_Due, 1Jur_DtDue, 1Jur_FinalDue, 1Jur_DtPaid, 1Jur_Thru, 2Jur_Yr, 2Jur_Install, 2Jur_Amt, 2Jur_Paid, 2Jur_Due, 2Jur_DtDue, 2Jur_FinalDue, 2Jur_DtPaid, 2Jur_Thru, 3Jur_Yr, 3Jur_Install, 3Jur_Amt, 3Jur_Paid, 3Jur_Due, 3Jur_DtDue, 3Jur_FinalDue, 3Jur_DtPaid, 3Jur_Thru, 4Jur_Yr, 4Jur_Install, 4Jur_Amt, 4Jur_Paid, 4Jur_Due, 4Jur_DtDue, 4Jur_FinalDue, 4Jur_DtPaid, 4Jur_Thru, Jur_PayNotes, Jur_OtherNotes, MillageRate, AssessedValue, LandValue, ImprovedValue, TotalValue, 1Jur_DelAmount, 2Jur_DelAmount, 3Jur_DelAmount, 4Jur_DelAmount, Unincorporated, Ex_Homestead, Ex_Disabled, Ex_Veteran, Ex_Mortgage, Ex_Star, Ex_Elderly, Ex_Other, 1Jur_Del, 2Jur_Del, 3Jur_Del, 4Jur_Del, DelVerifiedBy, MilNextDue, DelOverideNotes, SpokeTo, LumpSum, SchoolTax, PriorYearDel, 1Jur_Partial, 2Jur_Partial, 3Jur_Partial, 4Jur_Partial, 1Jur_Timely, 2Jur_Timely, 3Jur_Timely, 4Jur_Timely, 1Jur_FrDue, 2Jur_FrDue, 3Jur_FrDue, 4Jur_FrDue, LowestDiscount, PaidDiscount, NoDiscount, PrimaryAuth, OtherAuth, MultiParcel, LandImprov, PriorYearDelq, AnyRedeemed, SpecialAssess, AnyExemptions, NextYearAssessment, LastYearPaid, TaxSale, TaxRateArea, Ex_OwnerOccupied) VALUES (1291922, 1168, '', '', '2013', '1', 452.55, 452.55, , '9/30/2012 12:00:00 AM', '10/1/2012 12:00:00 AM', '9/30/2012 12:00:00 AM', '', '2013', '2', 452.55, 452.55, , '12/31/2012 12:00:00 AM', '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM', '12/31/2012 12:00:00 AM', '', '2013', '3', 452.55, 452.55, , '3/31/2013 12:00:00 AM', '4/1/2013 12:00:00 AM', '3/31/2013 12:00:00 AM', '', '2013', '4', 452.55, 452.55, , '6/5/2013 12:00:00 AM', '6/6/2013 12:00:00 AM', '6/5/2013 12:00:00 AM', '', '', 'There are no special assessments for this property.', 1.05, 172400, 30000, 142400, 172400, , , , , 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', '', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', '', 9/30/2013 12:00:00 AM, '', '', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', '9/1/2012 12:00:00 AM', '9/1/2012 12:00:00 AM', '9/1/2012 12:00:00 AM', '9/1/2012 12:00:00 AM', , 'False', 'False', 'False', 'Yes', 'No', 'Land and Improvements', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', , '', '', '', 'False');
```

Comment: Post what cmd.CommandText is before you do the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), it is hard to tell where the problem is exactly without the full sql string.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you should never ignore SQL injection, the proper use of parameters would solve this issue for you, as well as make it much easier to troubleshoot now and maintain in the future when you need to change it. Do it correctly now and save yourself the headaches (and risks that you might not imagine possible now).

Comment: Are these `datetime` columns in the Database?

Comment: "however, this program will be internal use only and does not run the risk of this."  Famous last words... :)

Comment: You have an empty comma set in your insert. `, ,` just before the time insertion.

Answer (score 2):

You have several empty comma sets in your insert. `, ,` just before the time insertion.

You might try `,'',` or `,NULL,`

Comment: Those blank comma areas are fields in the table that are blank. The spots with `,' ',` are text or Date/time fields and the spots with , , are either currency fields. Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: If you're not going to insert anything for those columns you can leave the columns out of the declaration (as long as you have a default value set in the table).

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and did the SQL Parameters way (the right way) and that fixed my problem.

' work smarter , not harder '

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                {
                    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `" + TableName + "`";
                    cmd.CommandText += "(ControlNumber, Jur_ID, Jur_Status, Jur_Collected, 1Jur_Yr, 1Jur_Install, 1Jur_Amt, 1Jur_Paid, 1Jur_Due, 1Jur_DtDue, 1Jur_FinalDue, 1Jur_DtPaid, 1Jur_Thru, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "2Jur_Yr, 2Jur_Install, 2Jur_Amt, 2Jur_Paid, 2Jur_Due, 2Jur_DtDue, 2Jur_FinalDue, 2Jur_DtPaid, 2Jur_Thru, 3Jur_Yr, 3Jur_Install, 3Jur_Amt, 3Jur_Paid, 3Jur_Due, 3Jur_DtDue, 3Jur_FinalDue, 3Jur_DtPaid, 3Jur_Thru, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "4Jur_Yr, 4Jur_Install, 4Jur_Amt, 4Jur_Paid, 4Jur_Due, 4Jur_DtDue, 4Jur_FinalDue, 4Jur_DtPaid, 4Jur_Thru, Jur_PayNotes, Jur_OtherNotes, MillageRate, AssessedValue, LandValue, ImprovedValue, TotalValue, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "1Jur_DelAmount, 2Jur_DelAmount, 3Jur_DelAmount, 4Jur_DelAmount, Unincorporated, Ex_Homestead, Ex_Disabled, Ex_Veteran, Ex_Mortgage, Ex_Star, Ex_Elderly, Ex_Other, 1Jur_Del, 2Jur_Del, 3Jur_Del, 4Jur_Del, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "DelVerifiedBy, MilNextDue, DelOverideNotes, SpokeTo, LumpSum, SchoolTax, PriorYearDel, 1Jur_Partial, 2Jur_Partial, 3Jur_Partial, 4Jur_Partial, 1Jur_Timely, 2Jur_Timely, 3Jur_Timely, 4Jur_Timely, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "1Jur_FrDue, 2Jur_FrDue, 3Jur_FrDue, 4Jur_FrDue, LowestDiscount, PaidDiscount, NoDiscount, PrimaryAuth, OtherAuth, MultiParcel, LandImprov, PriorYearDelq, AnyRedeemed, SpecialAssess, AnyExemptions, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "NextYearAssessment, LastYearPaid, TaxSale, TaxRateArea, Ex_OwnerOccupied) ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "VALUES ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "(@ControlNumber, @Jur_ID, @Jur_Status, @Jur_Collected, @1Jur_Yr, @1Jur_Install, @1Jur_Amt, @1Jur_Paid, @1Jur_Due, @1Jur_DtDue, @1Jur_FinalDue, @1Jur_DtPaid, @1Jur_Thru, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "@2Jur_Yr, @2Jur_Install, @2Jur_Amt, @2Jur_Paid, @2Jur_Due, @2Jur_DtDue, @2Jur_FinalDue, @2Jur_DtPaid, @2Jur_Thru, @3Jur_Yr, @3Jur_Install, @3Jur_Amt, @3Jur_Paid, @3Jur_Due, @3Jur_DtDue, @3Jur_FinalDue, @3Jur_DtPaid, @3Jur_Thru, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "@4Jur_Yr, @4Jur_Install, @4Jur_Amt, @4Jur_Paid, @4Jur_Due, @4Jur_DtDue, @4Jur_FinalDue, @4Jur_DtPaid, @4Jur_Thru, @Jur_PayNotes, @Jur_OtherNotes, @MillageRate, @AssessedValue, @LandValue, @ImprovedValue, @TotalValue, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "@1Jur_DelAmount, @2Jur_DelAmount, @3Jur_DelAmount, @4Jur_DelAmount, @Unincorporated, @Ex_Homestead, @Ex_Disabled, @Ex_Veteran, @Ex_Mortgage, @Ex_Star, @Ex_Elderly, @Ex_Other, @1Jur_Del, @2Jur_Del, @3Jur_Del, @4Jur_Del, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "@DelVerifiedBy, @MilNextDue, @DelOverideNotes, @SpokeTo, @LumpSum, @SchoolTax, @PriorYearDel, @1Jur_Partial, @2Jur_Partial, @3Jur_Partial, @4Jur_Partial, @1Jur_Timely, @2Jur_Timely, @3Jur_Timely, @4Jur_Timely, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "@1Jur_FrDue, @2Jur_FrDue, @3Jur_FrDue, @4Jur_FrDue, @LowestDiscount, @PaidDiscount, @NoDiscount, @PrimaryAuth, @OtherAuth, @MultiParcel, @LandImprov, @PriorYearDelq, @AnyRedeemed, @SpecialAssess, @AnyExemptions, ";
                    cmd.CommandText += "@NextYearAssessment, @LastYearPaid, @TaxSale, @TaxRateArea, @Ex_OwnerOccupied); ";


                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ControlNumber", r["ControlNumber"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jur_Id", r["Jur_ID"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jur_Status", r["Jur_Status"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jur_Collected", r["Jur_Collected"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Yr", r["1Jur_Yr"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Install", r["1Jur_Install"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Amt", r["1Jur_Amt"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Paid", r["1Jur_Paid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Due", r["1Jur_Due"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_DtDue", r["1Jur_DtDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_FinalDue", r["1Jur_FinalDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_DtPaid", r["1Jur_DtPaid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Thru", r["1Jur_Thru"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Yr", r["2Jur_Yr"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Install", r["2Jur_Install"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Amt", r["2Jur_Amt"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Paid", r["2Jur_Paid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Due", r["2Jur_Due"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_DtDue", r["2Jur_DtDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_FinalDue", r["2Jur_FinalDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_DtPaid", r["2Jur_DtPaid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Thru", r["2Jur_Thru"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Yr", r["3Jur_Yr"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Install", r["3Jur_Install"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Amt", r["3Jur_Amt"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Paid", r["3Jur_Paid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Due", r["3Jur_Due"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_DtDue", r["3Jur_DtDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_FinalDue", r["3Jur_FinalDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_DtPaid", r["3Jur_DtPaid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Thru", r["3Jur_Thru"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Yr", r["4Jur_Yr"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Install", r["4Jur_Install"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Amt", r["4Jur_Amt"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Paid", r["4Jur_Paid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Due", r["4Jur_Due"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_DtDue", r["4Jur_DtDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_FinalDue", r["4Jur_FinalDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_DtPaid", r["4Jur_DtPaid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Thru", r["4Jur_Thru"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jur_PayNotes", r["Jur_PayNotes"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jur_OtherNotes", r["Jur_otherNotes"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MillageRate", r["MillageRate"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AssessedValue", r["AssessedValue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LandValue", r["LandValue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImprovedValue", r["ImprovedValue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalValue", r["TotalValue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_DelAmount", r["1Jur_DelAmount"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_DelAmount", r["2Jur_DelAmount"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_DelAmount", r["3Jur_DelAmount"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_DelAmount", r["4Jur_DelAmount"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unincorporated", r["Unincorporated"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ex_Homestead", r["Ex_Homestead"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ex_Disabled", r["Ex_Disabled"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ex_Veteran", r["Ex_Veteran"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ex_Mortgage", r["Ex_Mortgage"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ex_Star", r["Ex_Star"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ex_Elderly", r["Ex_Elderly"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ex_Other", r["Ex_Other"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Del", r["1Jur_Del"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Del", r["2Jur_Del"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Del", r["3Jur_Del"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Del", r["4Jur_Del"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DelVerifiedBy", r["DelVerifiedBy"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MilNextDue", r["MilNextDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DelOverideNotes", r["DelOverideNotes"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SpokeTo", r["SpokeTo"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LumpSum", r["LumpSum"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SchoolTax", r["SchoolTax"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PriorYearDel", r["PriorYearDel"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Partial", r["1Jur_Partial"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Partial", r["2Jur_Partial"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Partial", r["3Jur_Partial"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Partial", r["4Jur_Partial"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_Timely", r["1Jur_Timely"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_Timely", r["2Jur_Timely"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_Timely", r["3Jur_Timely"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_Timely", r["4Jur_Timely"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@1Jur_FrDue", r["1Jur_FrDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@2Jur_FrDue", r["2Jur_FrDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@3Jur_FrDue", r["3Jur_FrDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@4Jur_FrDue", r["4Jur_FrDue"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LowestDiscount", r["LowestDiscount"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PaidDiscount", r["PaidDiscount"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoDiscount", r["NoDiscount"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrimaryAuth", r["PrimaryAuth"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OtherAuth", r["OtherAuth"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MultiParcel", r["MultiParcel"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LandImprov", r["LandImprov"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PriorYearDelq", r["PriorYearDelq"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AnyRedeemed", r["AnyRedeemed"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SpecialAssess", r["SpecialAssess"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AnyExemptions", r["AnyExemptions"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NextYearAssessment", r["NextYearAssessment"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastYearPaid", r["LastYearPaid"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxSale", r["TaxSale"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxRateArea", r["TaxRateArea"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ex_OwnerOccupied", r["Ex_OwnerOccupied"]);

                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take your own solution a step further... You are rebuilding the command, string and parameters for EVERY record.  I would adjust in the following fashion...

(assuming you have at least one row and you tested for that)

```
DataRow r = dt.Rows[0];

cmd = ...
cmd.CommandText = ... (as you already have parameterized).
```

Define the parameters ONCE (as you have).

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ControlNumber", r["ControlNumber"]);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jur_Id", r["Jur_ID"]);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Jur_Status", r["Jur_Status"]);
...
```

Now, you have your command all built and parameters in place...  NOW, you can just go through each row and just update the parameters value for each row (so it doesn't have to keep rebuilding the parameters and all the overhead with creating every time)...

```
foreach (DataRow r2 in dt.Rows)
{
    // just keep the parameters in the same sequence as you have when creating
    // you just update the value that will be applied when executed.
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = r2["ControlNumber"]);
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = r2["Jur_ID"]);
    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = r2["Jur_Status"]);
    ...

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```